# Выборка элементов JQuery

Tags: jquery, frontend

Как мне выбрать элемент `<input>` используя одновременно и аттрибут `name` и конкреный `class`

К примеру такие инпуты:

```
<input name='coolName' class='test disN'/>
<input name='coolName' class='test'/>
<input name='coolName' class='test'/>
```

нужно выбрать инпут с `name='coolName'` и `class='disN'`

Comment: @Igor прошу прощения - исправился)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input.disN[name='coolName']")
```

> у которых нет класса `disN`

```
$("input[name='coolName']").not(".disN")

$("input[name='coolName']:not(.disN)")
```

Comment: еще хочу на будущее уточнить - если я хочу фильрануть наоборот - у которых нет класса `disN`

Comment: можно я Вас еще раз дерну, - к примеру инпут радиокнопка - все инпуты с именем и чекед кнопкой.

Comment: @РоманТимохов `input[type='radio'][name='coolName']:checked` -  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp